# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException - Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to reference VB 6.0 dll in my Vb.net code and i am getting this error.

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException - Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record**

This legacy method which i am trying to call is tested and working good in vb 6.0, but when i tried to reference that i am getting above error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may be performing MoveFirst / MoveLast operation on a  recordset and recordset do not having any rows. I got the same issue and resolved by putting check for EOF or BOF.